# Algorithm to compute all possible chords on a guitar (i.e. all possible note combinations), given a set of notes that go in the chord?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I am trying to create a function/algorithm which takes a list of notes, like the C Major chord notes of `C E G`, and for a 6-stringed guitar (or n-stringed instrument), which has a particular "*tuning*" (note per fret per string), and figures out all the possible chord variations it can make on the fretboard. The variations can be 3 notes minimum (to satisfy the definition of a chord), and maximum the number of strings, so the chord can have 6 notes on the guitar.

How do you get back a list of chords like this (grouped by number of strings in chord)?

```
[
  {
    chordSize: 3,
    chords: [
      [
        // 0 indexed strings, 1 indexed frets, since the open string is fret 0
        { string: 1, fret: 3, note: "C" },
        { string: 2, fret: 2, note: "E" },
        { string: 3, fret: 0, note: "G" },
      ],
      [
        { string: 2, fret: 2, note: "E" },
        { string: 3, fret: 0, note: "G" },
        { string: 4, fret: 1, note: "C" },
      ],
      [
        { string: 3, fret: 0, note: "G" },
        { string: 4, fret: 1, note: "C" },
        { string: 5, fret: 0, note: "E" },
      ],
      // ...
    ],
  },
  {
    chordSize: 4,
    chords: [
      [
        { string: 1, fret: 3, note: "C" },
        { string: 2, fret: 2, note: "E" },
        { string: 3, fret: 0, note: "G" },
        { string: 4, fret: 1, note: "C" },
      ],
      // ...
    ],
  },
  {
    chordSize: 5,
    chords: [
      [
        { string: 1, fret: 3, note: "C" },
        { string: 2, fret: 2, note: "E" },
        { string: 3, fret: 0, note: "G" },
        { string: 4, fret: 1, note: "C" },
        { string: 5, fret: 0, note: "E" },
      ],
    ],
    // ...
  },
  // ...
]
```

That assumes a chord like this on the guitar:

[image]

I get stuck at how complex this algorithm seems at first:

```
function getPossibleStringedInstrumentChords({
  numStrings = 6, notes, tuning, maxFretDistance = 6
}) {
  // tuning is a list of strings, for each fret, marking the note.
  // tuning = [ [ 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', ... ], ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', ...] ]
  
  // notes is an array like ['C', 'E', 'G' ]

  let i = 3 // minimum number of notes in a chord is 3.
  while (i <= numStrings) {
    let stringIndex = 0
    let fretIndex = 0
    let string = tuning[stringIndex]

    while (fretIndex < string.length) {
      const note = string[fretIndex++]
      if (notes.includes(note)) {
        // add it to the set...
      } else {
        // it's like parsing recursively, multiple trees
        // my brain starts to explode!
      }
    }
    i++
  }
}
```

The tunings can be these notes, starting with any of them and ending with the last one in the loop. Let's say there can be 24 frets, so there are 2 full octaves basically, or two 12 sets of notes per string.

```
const POSSIBLE_NOTES = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#']
```

A tuning for the guitar would be like:

```
const GUITAR_TUNING = [
  ["E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#"],
  ["A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"],
  ["D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#"],
  ["G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#"],
  ["B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#"],
  ["E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#"],
]
```

How can you figure out this algorithm to generate all possible chords from 3-6 strings in length? It has been mind-bending for me.

Some other notes:

- Let's say a chord variation is 3 notes. Those notes can be on any 3 strings, not just sequential strings.
- Given 3 strings and one chord to lookup, there can be many placements of the chord on those 3 strings alone (probably different octaves).

Comment: [Here](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/135150/51238) perhaps is a very clever solution, though I have yet to wrap my head around it. Didn't think you could solve it way differently than what I'm trying in this current post...

Comment: I was in the middle of writing my answer when you posted this link so now it would just be redundant... I'm actually learning how to play the guitar currently so this question was pretty interesting for me. Just cus I'm curious, why on earth do you need such a program? LOL

Comment: @Jonathan Please finish your answer! I don't fully understand their answer yet :). I want to make a rendering of every chord and see how it looks, make flash cards. Specifically I want to play with chiseling down the list of chords to those that are useful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [you shouldn't cross-post questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and this was cross-posted [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/135148/how-to-convert-tonicjs-tonic-chord-data-to-guitar-chords/135150#135150)

Comment: Oh man this really is much more complicated than I thought. I've been trying for a while now and I don't seem to get it quite right. I will continue this later. Can you clarify a few things though for now. C,E,G. They can also be: C,E,G,C,C,G for example? how exactly must each chord look like? do they need to atleast have C,E,G or could they also be C,C,C? or E,G,E,G

Comment: @Jonathan haha nice! They need to have all of the notes (CEG), but can have duplicate notes (CEGCCG). CCC and EGEG don't count. Also, a chord may have 4 or 5 different notes, not just 3.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I took so long I completely forgot about this.

I think I was on the right path the last time I tried solving this but I can't find my code. Anyway, since recursive algorithms kept me up at night in CS class, Forgive me but I will not write it from scratch again.

ANYWAYS, I'll briefly tell you what my approach was.

```
    const GUITAR_TUNING = [
  ["E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#"],
  ["A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"],
  ["D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#"],
  ["G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#"],
  ["B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#"],
  ["E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#"],
]
```

using this list, I would return coordinates to represent chords. and then translate it back when necessary to notes, which is easy.
Basically, the recursive function will work like this:

1. Get the chord `C E G`.
2. find the first instance of one of the notes
3. store its location in a 2d array. the location of the first note in this case would be [0,0]
4. Now add the second note that appears, in order, even if it's repetitive.
5. once the current chord answers two conditions (Length>=3 && has(E, C, G)) you can add this chord to a larger 2d array. this one contains all of the completed chords.

pretty straightforward.
there are a few exceptions that are harder to crack but I'm not even sure if they are that necessary. for example: EEEECG. this algorithm won't find this.

I don't even know if you're still at this problem but hope I helped anyway.

If you are still completely out of ideas, let me know, and perhaps I'll conquer my greatest enemy for you, a recursive function.. Cheers (;